# Mongo Multiple Level Aggregate Lookup Group

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 3 collections, User, Dispensary and City. I want my result to look like this:

```
{
    _id: ,
    email: ,
    birthdate: ,
    type: ,
    dispensary: {
      _id: ,
      schedule: ,
      name: ,
      address: ,
      phone: ,
      user:,
      city: {
         name:,
        },
    },
  }
```

However I am getting the city object out, in the first level, and I want to get it as child of the dispensary collection.

This is my current pipeline I'm using:

```
    User.aggregate
              ([
                {
                  $match: { "_id": id } 
                },
                {
                  $lookup:
                  {
                    from: Dispensary.collection.name,
                    localField: "dispensary",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "dispensary"
                  },
                },
                {"$unwind": {path:"$dispensary",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} ,},
                {
                  $lookup:
                  {
                    from: City.collection.name,
                    localField: "dispensary.city",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "city"
                  },
                },
                {"$unwind": {path:"$city",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}} ,
                {
                  "$group": {
                  _id: "$_id", 
                  email : { $first: '$email' },
                  birthdate : { $first: '$birthdate' },
                  type : { $first: '$type' },
                  dispensary: { $push:  "$dispensary" }, 
                  city: { $push:  "$city" }, 
                  },
                },
                {"$unwind": {path:"$dispensary",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}} ,
                {"$unwind": {path:"$city",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}} ,

              ], (aggErr, aggResult) => {
                (aggErr)  ? console.log(aggResult)
                          : console.log(aggResult)
              })
```

SCHEMAS:

```
const CitySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique:true },
    zip: { type: String, required: true },
});

const DispensarySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    longitude: { type: String, required: true },
    latitude: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: String, required: true },
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    schedule: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Schedule'}],
    city: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City'},
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type:String, required: true },
    birthdate: { type: Date, required: true },
    type: { type: String, enum: ['ADMIN','DISPENSARY','CUSTOMER'], required: true},
    verificationToken: { type: String, required: false },
    resetPasswordToken: { type: String, required: false },
    resetPasswordExpires: { type: String, required: false },
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    last_session: { type: Date },
    last_ip_session: { type:String },
    dispensary: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Dispensary'},
},
{ timestamps: true }
)
```

Comment: You should attach the schema of each collection as it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Your expected output at `dispensary` is an object. Why do you use `$push` to get an array? Should it be an array?

Comment: I use push to add it to the root array as dispensary, and i want to do that with city tho, add city inside the dispensary but i see that it doesnt allow to create 3 levels in one group, i was trying to add a second group stage but I didnt reach it

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `$group` at all, you can use `as: "dispensary.city"` in your second `$lookup`

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": id
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: Dispensary.collection.name,
      localField: "dispensary",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dispensary"
    },
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$dispensary",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    },
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: City.collection.name,
      localField: "dispensary.city",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dispensary.city" // modify here
    },
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$dispensary.city", // modify here
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: how can I unwind it? since it's coming as [Object]

Comment: `dispensary.city` should already be an object, you might want to check you have any extra `$lookup`s. From my answer you should only have 2 `$lookup`s

Comment: @AnthonyMedina Where are you viewing this? `[Object]` might be correct already but your client doesn't display it

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/R7wKgLA.jpg

forget the last pic, this is the correct one

Comment: Please check that you correctly `$unwind` at the path `"$dispensary.city"` as the last stage in the answer

Comment: im using morgan

Comment: Should be correct already. It just doesn't display the whole output. Try `console.dir(output, { depth: null })` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(output))` to see the full output

Comment: Ok I tried it with sending to my frontend made in react and it didn't work as expected, I see the response from the server, there is comming the expected array but there is an error when It try to parse

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream is locked

It didn't hapened in others cases, any idea? I still thinking that's about the fail unwind, morfan should show it because I did longer queries using morgan without issues

Comment: The error is more about how you handle the response. I'm confident the `$unwind` is correct if your `city` is correct. At least try to do JSON.stringify on the output or do log `output.map(record => record.dispensary && record.dispensary.city)` to see whether city is there or not

Comment: @AnthonyMedina If you want to see whether morgan can handle it or not try `console.log({ 1: {2: {3: {4: {5: 'hello' } } } } })`

Comment: The point is send it to the front, ill try to handle it

this is what im using now 

 return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);

Comment: You might be calling `response.tex()` multiple times. But this is entirely another issue. Also if it's meant to be parsed with JSON.parse() why not do `response.json(
)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can used another `lookup` method using `pipeline`, This allow you to make more condition/sub-query inside of the lookup function. see reference: [aggregate-lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
    User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "_id": id } 
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: Dispensary.collection.name,
      let: {dispensaryId: "$dispensary"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
               $eq: ["$_id", "$$dispensaryId"]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: City.collection.name,
            localField: "city",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "city"
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path:"$city",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
          }
        }
      ]
      as: "dispensary",
    },
  },
  {
     $unwind: {
       path:"$dispensary",
       preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
   },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: : {
        _id: "$_id", 
        email :  '$email' ,
        birthdate : '$birthdate' ,
        type :  '$type' 
        dispensary: "$dispensary"
     }
    }
  }
], (aggErr, aggResult) => {
  (aggErr)  ? console.log(aggResult)
            : console.log(aggResult)
})
```

Update: Pipeline NOTE: To reference variables in pipeline stages, use the "$$" syntax.`

Comment: dispensary: "$dispensary" <--- when I use this in the group, It always return Undefined, if I change it for a push ->  dispensary: { $push:  "$dispensary" },     ]
it works, but sadly with the pipeline in the first lookup the dispensary array comes as empty, 

that's because i'm using push?
why only work with push for me?

Comment: Ohh. I didnt see it clearly, the problem is on the `$group` pipeline, add all the fields inside of the `_id` property then try it again.

Comment: dispensary still coming empty, in this case it is working without push but comes empty, it seems to be hapening something wrong inside the pipeline of the first lookup

Comment: I updated again my answer above, I've used `$expr` to access the declared value on `let`. See the pipeline description here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/