# How to unbind nested objects, result of an one to many relationship with aggregate mongo

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I need help with mongo, I need to make a query resulting in a objext and many object nested resulting of a one to many relation ship of these schemas:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true, unique:true },
picture: { type: String },
description: { type: String, required: true },
isEnabled: { type: Boolean, required: true },
brand: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Brand' },
slug: { type: String, required: true },
category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Category' },
reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Review' }]


const PackageSchema = new Schema({
type: { type: String, enum:["WEIGHT", "EACH"], required: true },
value: { type: Number, required: true },
price: { type: Number, required: true },
stock: { type: Boolean, required: true},
description: { type: String, required: true},
product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Product', required: true },
dispensary: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Dispensary', required: true }
```

This is the code i made

```
const dispensaryID;
payload = _thisModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "packages",
            localField:'_id',
            foreignField:'product',
            as:"package"
        }
    },
    {"$unwind": {path:"$package", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}} ,
    {
        $group: 
        {
            _id:"$_id", 
            number: {
                $sum: "$package"
              },
            package: {$push: '$package'},
        }
    },

],(aggErr, aggResult) => {
      (aggErr)  ? console.log(aggResult)
                : console.log(aggResult)
})
```

Buy it is resulting on this:

```
  { _id: 5ebf98724ef6e503ccd7ae4f, clicks: 0, package: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    _id: 5ebf98614ef6e503ccd7ae4e,
    clicks: 0,
    package: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { _id: 5ebed37b52ec0043fca22893, clicks: 0, package: [] }
```

So i need to unbind those objects, I need to see the packages details instead some "[Object]", I tried reconfiguring the script but this is the nearest result I got, also I need to check if a dispensary: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Dispensary', required: true } given in the second schema exists in any of those packages, I will give a const to check if it maches, and add a prop says exists: true on the product object or only delete the whole product object with the packages.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The reason that you are seeing `[Object]` is likely because of `console.log` depth limit of showing nested object output. Try `console.dir(aggResult, { depth: null })` instead. On tother note, not sure what you are trying to `$sum`, it should be a number not an object.

Comment: thanks, you was right, what in case of check if the field exists?

Comment: Seems to be a separate issue, better to ask a new question to make it more focused for other people that see this

Comment: I think I have mentioned about `console.dir()` in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61730292) to your previous question as well, hope you already got that sorted out :)